# Chain together methods in Python as in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby, one can chain together methods like so:

```
a = [2,3,1]
b = a.sort.reverse
```

which sets the value of the variable `b` to `[3,2,1]` while leaving `a` the same.

I'd like to perform similar operations in Python. So far, the shortest way to do this I have found is:

```
import copy
a = [2,3,1]
b = copy.copy(a)
b.sort()
b.reverse()
```

That is, with 5 lines of code instead of 2. Is there really no simpler way?

Comment: You can't with methods that mutate objects in-place, they return `None`. Python isn't big on fluent interfaces in general. You could use `sorted(a, reverse=True)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clarification: The original answer is found below. As commented, the question is on chaining *in general*, not in any specific case. A clarification on this can be found at the end of this answer.

---

You can write this down pretty much directly.

```
a = [2,3,1]
b = sorted(a, reverse=True)
```

Even if you want to use only methods, you can do that rather straightforward as well:

```
a = [2,3,1]
b = a.copy()  # a[:] in python2
b.sort(reverse=True)
```

Python tends to be rather picky about implicit cloning. Copying references is cheap, copying objects is expensive. Since many python types are mutable, one can easily introduce subtle bugs when things are cloned (or not) by accident. Thus, most interfaces need you to explicitly clone things.

---

Chaining methods in `python` is possible. However, chains only apply to the objects *returned* by previous method (or function) calls.

Basically, chaining method calls is like chaining functions.

```
foo = they.method.method.method()
foo = my_func(your_func(their_func()))
```

Let's consider `[2,3,1].sort().reverse()`. This is actually equivalent to the following:

```
a = [2,3,1]
b = a.sort()
c = b.reverse()
```

Since `s.sort()` returns `None`, the third line will call `None.reverse()` - which is not defined for `None`.

Immutable types generally behave better here. For example, strings cannot be modified inplace - their methods *return* new strings. Thus,

```
s = "ab:cd".upper().center(20).partition(':')
print(s)
```

gives `('       AB', ':', 'CD        ')`.

Comment: Thanks; although `sorted(a, reverse=True)` is an alternative for this example, I wanted to check whether the 'chaining' of methods was possible in general since I might want to use it for more complicated methods such as `map` and `filter`.

Comment: In this case, you've picked a bad example, I'm afraid. You can chain methods *to the objects returned by previous methods*. For example, `a.sort` returns `None`, on which you could call methods, if it had any (you can actually call `a.sort().__hash__()`). Immutable types are better for this. Try `"ab:cd".upper().center(20).partition(':')`.

Answer (score 0):

To chain methods I can suggest the following. May not be considered good pythonianship, though :-).

```
a = [2,3,1]
[eval('a.'+f+'()') for f in ['sort', 'reverse']]
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the methods working on the original object and not on a copy.

Comment: If one wants to avoid `eval`, `[getattr(a, f)() for f in ['sort', 'reverse']]` should work as well.